# Can I edit Realm object without transaction in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-cocoa

In my project I need to send Realm Object in Request body. Before this operation, I need to replace some of values in object variables with another.

But I don't need to save new values, before I get success response from server.

In case when I don't opened transaction on changing I get error

```
'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

So, is there any way to modify Realm object without instant saving, but rather 'saving on success' case?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You can clone your realm object and use copied object for request

Comment: I thought about it, but the trick is - currently you can not make copy of Realm object, leaving original object fully immutable. See issue [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3381)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in this way:

1. clone your stored realm object:

   > var editableObject: MyRealmObjectClass?

   > ```
   > editableObject = MyRealmObjectClass(value: alreadyStoredObject)
   > ```
2. Then, all modification you need, you do over this cloned copy:

> `editableObject.someProper = newValue`

3. Then you send this copy in request body. And after success response from server, you do backward:

   alreadyStoredObject = MyRealmObjectClass(value: editableObject)
4. And after this you can write updated object into local db:

> ```
> let realm = try! Realm()
>     try? realm.write {
>       realm.add(alreadyStoredObject, update: true)
>     }
> ```

primaryKey of alreadyStoredObject won't be changed.

editableObject won't be saved and eventually will be discarded, after you leave your ViewController.

Answer (score -1):

You can begin a transaction using `realm.beginWrite()` and make the changes you want to make. If server call is a success then  you can commit the transaction `realm.commitWrite()` or else cancel the transaction `realm.cancelWrite()`.

Comment: Well if I correctly understood I'll have open transaction all along my request to server in this case. That's really bad idea.

Comment: Ideally one should have separate DB and network DTOs. Why is this a bad idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by separate DB and network DTOs? Two different objects?

Comment: Its good practice to maintain separate DTO to avoid changes in one affect changes in other.